# Search bar for structured data Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm quite new to swift... I have a data model class like this:

```
class PostDataModel: NSObject {

    var postID : Int = 0
    var postTitle : String = ""
    var postExcerpt : String = ""
    var postContent : String = ""
    var postThumbnailURL : String = ""
    var postUpdated : String = ""
    var postLink : String = ""
    var postSlug : String = ""
}
```

and I need to search in the postTitle the text edited in the search bar present in a view controller:

```
//MARK: - Search bar methods inside the view controller

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        print(searchBar.text!)
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        filteredTableData = postsArray.filter({$0.postTitle == searchBar.text})

        tablePosts.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {

            shouldShowSearchResults = false
            view.endEditing(true)

            tablePosts.reloadData()
        } else {

            shouldShowSearchResults = true
            filteredTableData = postsArray.filter({(item)  -> Bool in
              var stringMatch = item.postTitle.lowercased().range(of: searchBar.text!)
                return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
            })
            tablePosts.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Searching around I found solutions when there is only text to seek in a String, but how can I filter an array of PostDataModel according to the text contained in the title?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want to filter where title is equal to searchBar.text? Or can you explain what does  "text contained in the title" mean

Comment: The code posted in your question does what you are asking (though it can be written better). So what issue are you actually having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lowercased text in `searchBar.text` too.

```
var stringMatch = item.postTitle.lowercased().range(of: searchBar.text!.lowercased())
```